# Canvas buttons become invisible on android build when adding material in Unity

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, button, canvas

When adding material to any canvas button and building the game onto my Android device the button is no longer visible. However, when I run it on my computer I could see everything. This wasn't always the case, just yesterday the buttons were visible when running it with material on my device. Now, the only way I can see the buttons on Android is if I remove the material. I know that it is not my Android device because I tried multiple devices and got the same outcome. I am using the Unity version 2018.2.2f1. I also tried downgrading to versions 2018.2.1f1 and 2018.1.6f1 but still nothing. Please help.

Comment: Can you share in your question how the material and shader is configured? It might be different drawing orders or z buffer that causes that. You can test that by disabling everything behind your buttons, because the might be rendered in front of your buttons.

Comment: Turns out the plane that I added on my camera as a background was covering the buttons when I rendered. Thank you so much! How would I fix this issue? Would I just change the z-axis of my buttons?

Comment: you could adjust the z-axis of your button or setup the canvas plane distance or enable/disable z buffer in the shader.